# Pass Class as parameter and return same class object

Tags: java, android, generics, collections

I want to pass Class as parameter and return the same class as parameter. 
Parameter can be any of the class. so I want comman method in which I need to pass only object of particular class and it will give me same object as return. 
I know with Java - Generics or with java collection it is possible but I don't know how?

Code:

```
 public Class_object_as_paramter(parent) webCall(Class Obj as parameter(parent))
                throws JsonSyntaxException, IOException, XmlPullParserException {
            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            parent = (Collection<?>) gson.fromJson(SoaplCalls
                    .GetUserwiseSalesContracts(GsonExample.this, "55000024"),
                    ParentSalesContract.class (also has to pass same class here);
            return parent;
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create generic method like this:

```
<T> T method(T t) {
    ...
    T tt = ...
    return tt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T> T webCall(T type)
{
   return type;  
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class GenericsExample <T> {
  public T webCall(T parent) {
    // ...
    T ret = ??; // Might be parent, might be a new class...
    return ret;
  }
}
```